# C# Properties.Settings missing

Tags: c#, properties, settings

I messed up the C# Properties. I worked on my project and changed a boolean in my Properties (Using the VS GUI). I simply changed it from True to False, at least I didn't notice anything else.

Now my whole project is broken.
I got around 200 errors messages all the same:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error CS0234 The type or namespace name "Settings" does not exist in the "MyProject.Properties" namespace. (An assembly reference may be missing.)

Also if I type Properties.S it doesn't show "Settings" anymore. Only Resources. It's gone.

[image: Screenshot]

Anyone has a idea how to fix this?

PS: I tried to revert the latest changes using a shortcut, but it didn't help.

Comment: Seems like a job for source control rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I luckily had a backup of my Properties folder. I simply replaced it. I will leave the question here, maybe someone could still give tips on this for other users, who may don't have any backup of their Properties folder.